# Please provide example of Nested list in C#.net

Tags: c#, list, nested-lists

How can i add list to another list, eg:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
```

I want to add this list to another list, something like:

```
List<List> list2 = new List<List>()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic"?

Answer (score 5):

```
var list1 = new List<string>();
var list2 = new List<string>();
var parentList = new List<List<string>> {list1, list2};
```

Comment: None of this will compile.

Comment: Was in the middle of editing it since the question was edited. It will definitely compile. You may need `using System.Collections.Generic`

Answer (score 1):

Create nested classes, and in each class a property of type List(Of xxSubClassxx)

a vb example would be:

```
class list1

 property list as new List(of xfirstlist)

 class xfirstlist

   property list2 as new list(of xSecondList)
   class xSecondList

   end class

 end class

end class
```